# ccavenue payment gateway errors like 10002

Tags: php, ajax, api, paypal, ccavenue

I am using cc-avenue kit for integration in zend. I have used the code which is provided by cc-avenue but when try to checkout from my site it gives an error

```
Code: 10002     Merchant Authentication failed.

Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.
```

in cc-avenue url .

Comment: hi  can anyone help me out ?

Comment: hi all i need your help i have tried so much but i am not getting any good solution in googling. help needed

Comment: how was this resolved ? I have the same issue

Comment: 022 - 67425555  Customer support @ccAvenue

Answer (score 3):

Error Code: 10002
Explanation: WHMCS system URL is not matching with the URL setup at CCAvenue MCPG gateway settings. For an example If your WHMCS system URL be http://subdomain.yourdomain.com then at your CCAvenue MCPG gateway settings page the URL should be http://subdomain.yourdomain.com. Also note http or https should also be matched.

Comment: where do we change this, I am testing on localhost.

Comment: IN the ccavenue merchant account

Comment: I don't think we can change it. We need to ask their support staff. Please tell me the exact steps to change or add new URLs for whitelisting. Thanks

Comment: Better ask to the support staff.(live chat is available)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have missed to add the value for the field **"Merchant Id"**. In every kit provided by ccavenue there is field called **"Merchant Id"** will be available in the form. Please use the merchant id provided by ccavenue. You can get the "Merchant Id" in your ccavenue admin panel.

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

A quick note to those looking at this error when using woocommerce plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/ccavenue-payment-gateway-woocommerce/ :
Depending on if CCavenue has switched you to their new setup you may need to use the older version of this plugin - v1.2.3

This resolved the problem I had.